# (iOS) Add data from json in array

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, json

I am a begginer in iOS and i've got a little problem. I don't know how to get a data from JSONObject for the index i, and for the key x.

Just below, there is my code

```
-(NSMutableArray*)getAll{
    NSMutableArray* liste;

    dispatch_queue_t downloadQueue = dispatch_queue_create("Get All Offers", NULL);

    dispatch_async(downloadQueue, ^{
        NSData *result = [self executePostCall];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

            id strResult=nil;
            NSError* error;
            strResult = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:result options:0 error:&error];
            for(int cpt=0; cpt>[strResult count];cpt++)
            {
                [liste addObject:[NSMutableArray new]];

                // ERREUR ICI !!!!!!!!!

                [[liste objectAtIndex:cpt] addObject:[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@",[[strResult  objectAtIndex:cpt] objectForKey:@"titre"]]];
                [[liste objectAtIndex:cpt] addObject:[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@",[[strResult objectAtIndex:cpt] objectForKey:@"srcImage"]]];
                [[liste objectAtIndex:cpt] addObject:[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@",[[strResult  objectAtIndex:cpt] objectForKey:@"date"]]];
                [[liste objectAtIndex:cpt] addObject:[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@",[[strResult  objectAtIndex:cpt] objectForKey:@"prix"]]];
                [[liste objectAtIndex:cpt] addObject:[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@",[[strResult  objectAtIndex:cpt] objectForKey:@"ville"]]];
                [[liste objectAtIndex:cpt] addObject:[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@",[[strResult objectAtIndex:cpt] objectForKey:@"categorie"]]];
            }


        });
    });
     NSLog(@"liste: %@",liste);
    return liste;
}
```

I tried to get the object with the key (for example "titre") at the line cpt. Can you help me please ?

I think the problem is when i'm doing `[[liste objectAtIndex:cpt] addObject:[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@",[[strResult  objectAtIndex:cpt] objectForKey:@"titre"]]];` but i don't know how to solve it.

`[self executePostCall]` is another function which works fine.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Could you show what looks like your JSON response?

Comment: @Larme the code is just below, thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the JSON, the object returned from `[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData]` is either an `NSArray` or `NSDictionary`. If `objectAtIndex` doesn't work, chances are you are dealing with an `NSDictionary`.

The safest way to go is to check which one it is in your code:

```
if([strResult isKindOfClass:NSArray.class]) {
    // Do something that deals with an array

} else if([strResult isKindOfClass:NSDictionary.class]) {
    // Do something that deals with a dictionary

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the answers @Larme & @Bob Vork.

Just below the executePostCall method:

```
- (NSData *)executePostCall {
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", @"http://www.mysite.com/listAllAnn.php"]];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

NSString *requestFields = @"";
requestFields = [requestFields stringByAppendingFormat:@"table=%@&", table];
requestFields = [requestFields stringByAppendingFormat:@"limit=%d&", limit];
requestFields = [requestFields stringByAppendingFormat:@"offset=%d", offset];

requestFields = [requestFields stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSData *requestData = [requestFields dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
request.HTTPBody = requestData;
request.HTTPMethod = @"POST";


NSHTTPURLResponse *response = nil;
NSError *error = nil;
NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
if (error == nil && response.statusCode == 200) {
} else {
    //Error handling
}
return responseData;

}
```

And this is the webservice "listAllAnn.php" I use to get informations from MySQL database. I am pretty sure that it is ok, because my workmate use it for Android application.

```
<?php

$response = array();

$db = new DB_CONNECT();

mysql_query('SET CHARACTER SET utf8');


$table=$_POST["table"];
$limit=$_POST["limit"];
$offset=$_POST["offset"];

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $table WHERE etat = 2 order by date DESC LIMIT $limit OFFSET $offset") or die(mysql_error());

if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {


while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $ann = array();
    $ann["id"] = $row["id_ann"];
    $ann["cat"] = $row["id_cat"];


    $response[]= $ann;

}

echo json_encode($response);
} else {
$response["success"] = 0;
$response["message"] = "No products found";

echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

the strResult objet sent me that when I make a NSLog

```
strResult:{
cat = 46;
id = 1496;
}
```

and When i do

```
NSLog(@"strResult: %@",[[strResult objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"id"]);
```

I got:

```
strResult: 1496
```

It's look like I have to use the code below to get info, but I don't know which key to use in the first "objectForKey" because i don't have any key in webservice except the ones i'm using to get infos.

```
[[liste objectAtIndex:cpt] addObject:[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@",[[[strResult  objectForKey:@""]objectAtIndex:cpt] objectForKey:@"titre"]]];
```

Comment: Please edit your original question with extra information rather than adding this in the section for answers.

Answer (score 1):

try initializaing liste

NSMutableArray* liste=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
Also you can directly use [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",xyz];

Hope it helps. Let me know the output.